# Angularjs location.path on same state not working

Tags: angularjs, path, location, logout

I am having issue when i try to logout and perform a location.path('/') to homepage.

Below is my code,

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('LogoutCtrl', function($location, $auth,$rootScope) {
    if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) { return; }


    $auth.logout()
      .then(function() {
          $auth.logout();
          $rootScope.user='';
          $location.path('/');
        });
  });
```

my app.js for this calling is :

```
.state('login.logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            template: null,
            controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
          })
```

I found that it is not redirecting when I perform the logout action in the same state. Which is http://localhost:8000/#/

But it will work when I'm in different state. Any guidance pls?

Comment: Try to use `$location.url('/');`.

Comment: tried and still dont work. I am using google chrome and i found that in my network tab, it did not re-load anything after i logged out.

Comment: Are you sure `$auth.logout().then()` is being executed/called?

Comment: yeah. I wrapped console.log() between the $location.path() and the code did executed. But somehow, it never load when I'm in the same page state, but it is working when I'm in different page (example: /contact).

Comment: Maybe you could try creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that recreate your problem so we can help you debug it.

Comment: I changed method to $state.go() and it is working now. Thanks for the help ! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you use ui-router for your redirects as well.
Have a 'home' state point to the '/' url

```
.state('Home', {
        url: '/',
        ....
      })
```

and then just do something like

```
$auth.logout()
  .then(function() {
  // do your cleanup
  return $state.go('Home');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

1.your using state provider, so whenever you want to redirect page using url need to use like
        $location.url('/'); 
if you want to use path then u need to pass state name as parameter for $location
        $location.path('/page/login');
here '/page/login' is your login or whatever page you want to redirect that page state.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "/";
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck.. it stuck at http://localhost:8000/#/login/logout without redirecting. =(

Comment: have you done a console.log() to see if the .then(function() is being called?

Comment: yeah, i tried two console.log wrapping the location.path() and both console.log is working.

Comment: I uses $state.go() and it is working now !. Thanks for helping